# How to highlight a layout while touch in Android?

Tags: android

How to highlight a layout while touch in Android?

Comment: just give two drawable so ontouch onclick u can give different backgrounds just check this same like this button http://blog.androgames.net/40/custom-button-style-and-theme/ give your layout two or three background

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters use `StateListDrawables` provided by android sdk. you can find its documentation here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html

An article on how to create a StateListDrawable:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList

Comment: +1 ya this will help her .. also this will help her http://blog.androgames.net/40/custom-button-style-and-theme/